# In proof of Straddle Lemma, how $ \left \lvert f(u)-f(c) - (u-c)f^\prime(c) \right\rvert \leq \varepsilon \lvert u-c \rvert = \varepsilon ( c-u )$?

Tags: real-analysis

[Saqqib Mahmood](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2914807)  was questioning Bartle, [*Introduction to Real Analysis* (2011 4 ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471433314), Section 6.1, Exercise 17, p 171. How did he deduce (2*) and (2**)  below? I'm flustered by all these variables $c, \delta, u, v, x$.

> Therefore we can conclude that
> $$ \left\lvert f(x)-f(c) - (x-c)f^\prime(c) \right\rvert \leq \varepsilon \lvert x - c \rvert \tag{2'} $$
> for all $x \in I$ for which $c-\delta(\varepsilon) < x < c+\delta(\varepsilon)$.

> From (2') we conclude that if $u, v \in I$ and $c-\delta(\varepsilon) < u \leq c \leq v < c + \delta(\varepsilon)$, then we have
> $$ \left\lvert f(u)-f(c) - (u-c)f^\prime(c) \right\rvert \leq \varepsilon \lvert u-c \rvert =  \varepsilon ( c-u ) \tag{2*} $$
> and also
> $$ \left\lvert f(v)-f(c) - (v-c)f^\prime(c) \right\rvert \leq \varepsilon \lvert v-c \rvert =  \varepsilon (v-c), \tag{2**} $$

Answer (score 0):

They're just rewriting (2') by considering the two cases $x \le c$ and $x \ge c$ separately (and renaming $x$ as $u$ and $v$ respectively).

For instance, if $c-\delta(\epsilon) < x < c + \delta(\epsilon)$ and $x \le c$, then (2') still applies, but you can replace $|x-c|$ with $(c-x)$. This gives (2*).